# Why double encode Jquery Ajax URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, urlencode

In my JS I use the jQuery ajax function.

Here how it looks like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "somepage/" + keyword + "/" + xyz + "/" + abc + "/getbla",
(...)
```

If the 'keyword' (= value of a textfield) contains a '#' this doesn't work anymore. We all know, that the URL will only be parsed until the # and the rest behind the # will be used eg for an anchor.

So I modified the ajax function to this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "somepage/" + encodeURIComponent(keyword) + "/" + xyz + "/" + abc + "/getbla",
(...)
```

This didn't work either, but in the console I can see the complete url with %23 instead of the #.

Ok this was close to what I was looking for, but the request still doesn't work - I don't know why - thats why I ask here.

I typed %23 in the textfield (=keyword) and the request works perfektly.
My php backend is sending back the data I was looking for.

So this is my final solution:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "somepage/" + encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(keyword)) + "/" + xyz + "/" + abc + "/getbla",
(...)
```

This is how the PHP-function looks like:

```
if ($_GET['anyparam'] == 'getbla') {

    $searchString = array(
        'keyword' => trim($_POST['keyword']),
        'xyz' => trim($_POST['xyz']),
        'abc' => trim($_POST['abc'])
    );

    echo json_encode($this->dataBaseFunctions->searchResult($searchString['keyword'], $searchString['xyz'], $searchString['abc']));
  }
```

**Question:** Why do I have to double encode the URL?

Comment: Why don't you send the values as `data`? O.o - `$.ajax({url: ..., data: { "keyword": ..., "xyz": ..., "abc": ... } /*...*/);`

Comment: Can you share some examples of the records being searched through by `$this->dataBaseFunctions->searchResult()`? Are they perhaps stored in your database as URL-encoded?

Comment: @Andreas: I already do. The data-attribute contains serialized form values.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: I can't say what users might search for. I tried something like 'test #1' and so I thought about those special characters. I don't want to limit user in this case.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that your using url rewriting, so the initial request goes through and the `#` is decoded and when redirected everything after the hash is thrown away.
For double encoding the first request will decode to `%23` the redirect to `#`

If you're using mod_rewrite take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: (at)Musa: Yes, I'm using rewrite rules here - well observed, it was my task to inform you about this additional information. Thanks for your explanation. But your solution results in a further question: What if I set the B flag in the appropiate rewrite rule but want to use the # as an anchor at the same time? Does this work?

Comment: If your url has an anchor (not encoded) your browser will not send it or anything after it in the request, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: OK this works so far. If the user types something like 'test #1' I can see all data. But i also want to call **somepage/test #1/123/**. If I replace all spaces to  '-' so there is something like **somepage/test-#1/123** this works for data without #. So in this case I have to deal with the '#' again. I tried this **somepage/test-%231/123/** But the server or the application is unable to find the requestet page then(404). **So why the server can't handle %23 here?**

Comment: **Only this here works:**
somepage/test-%2520%25231/123

Comment: Is that using the B flag?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this: RewriteRule ^somepage/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ somepage&param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,B]

Answer (score 0):

I think this rule is what I was looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^somepage/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ somepage&param1=${unesc:$1}&param2=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

[as per this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)  the url which you are entering without using encodeURIComponent is actually fine , you are just encoding the correct url which makes it incorrect , so you have to apply 2 times to make it go from correct->not correct->correct.